# Game minimizing during play

Tags: rocket-league

I have rocket league on epic games.  Occasionally the game will minimize during a match.  The game will still be visible, but movement input wont work until I click on the screen.  In critical moments this can be devestating.  I've seen people ask questions about this on the steam version, but not with epic games.  How do i prevent it from minimizing?

Comment: I've played 2.5k hours, and I saw this happen for the first time today.  I think this might be a new bug.

Comment: Wow, 2.5k hours.  I haven't even hit 200 yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/RocketLeague/comments/oabahw/the_game_minimize_itself/h3gk44f/), it's a bug that was recently added.  Psyonix has it on their [known bugs list](https://www.rocketleague.com/news/known-issues-in-rocket-league/).

As far as I can find no one knows of a workaround yet.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I imagine Psyonix will fix it eventually.

Comment: I find it funny how u mentioned that it's a bug "recently added" :D